# Download all RPM packages from CentOS repo?

Tags: package-management, yum, repository, dependencies

I have a server that should contain all the RPM packages downloaded from CentOS repository so that I can reach that server from another server which hasn't got internet access and get the up to date packages to itself.

The thing is that, because of dependency issue, I can't download all of the packages. Below there are the commands that I tried.

```
$ repotrack -p . -a x86_64 *.rpm
```

Above command downloads 194 RPM packages. When I try with *rpm, again the same result.

```
$ yum install --downloadonly --installroot=/etc/yum.downloads/packets-installroot --downloaddir=/etc/yum.downloads *.rpm
```

Above command downloads 179 RPM packages. When I try with *rpm, the packet count decreased.

```
$ yumdownloader --resolve --destdir=/etc/yum.downloads/ *.rpm
```

Above command downloads just 48 packages.

```
$ yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/etc/yum.downloads/ *rpm
```

Above command downloads just 48 packages.

These commands should download all RPM packages and dependencies whereas they don't. I'm trying the commands with specific 1 package also and they download its dependencies but whenever I try to download all packages, it fails to do that I guess.

UPDATE:

I tried below command

```
$ repoquery --qf=%{name} -g --list --grouppkgs=all [groups] | xargs repotrack -a x86_64 -p .
```

It downloaded 4640 packages but still there is a problem. -g commands query groups instead of packages. So there are packages that hasn't got groups and I need to download them as well.

`-a` parameter is the solution to that I believe because in the manual it says that `-a` "query all". But still I couldn't find the true syntax for that. Does anybody know?

Comment: if you have your OS iso you can use that.there`s a folder named Pacakges which contain all of them.

Comment: I know that but I will write a script when I find the solution. The script will automatically download the up-to-date packages from repo (centos or rhel) and after that, the other machine will get those packages

Comment: So basically you want to create internal repository, right? There are plenty of tutorials how to do it in the Internet. For example this one: https://www.tecmint.com/setup-yum-repository-in-centos-7/

Comment: I will definetely try rsync and write here if it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
repoquery -a | xargs repotrack -a x86_64 -p .

wget -A rpm -r -l 5 http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/ -P .
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

To list **all available packages** in a specified repository, do:

```
repoquery -a --repoid=REPONAME
```

To download all the packages, use **xargs** with **yumdownloader**

```
repoquery -a --repoid=REPONAME| xargs -i -t yumdownloader {}
```

when repoid is the name of your remote repo.